# Wordpress - Pagination for pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a page with the most rated posts.

I use WP-PostRatings and I use this code:

`query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );`

Is there a way to create pagination for pages?

I found something here [Wordpress pagination with static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312032/wordpress-pagination-with-static-pages) , but it shows me in all pages, the newest  posts, order by date (as in homepage)

Thank you!

Comment: looks i already answered a question similar to this [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374490/how-to-create-pagination/15376454#15376454)

Comment: thank you! but is not working for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get [pagination to work with `query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination) you need to [add the `$paged` variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query) to your query:

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = array( 
    'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts( $query );
```